# How to make CGContextShowTextAtPoint() automatically shrink text in some rectangle

Tags: objective-c, ios, text, size, cgcontext

I am doing manual drawing of text with CGContextShowTextAtPoint() because this text is being placed over an image and to be readable I draw this text first time with larger white lineWidth and then with smaller black lineWidth, because shadow doesn't give required readablity effect. Image is not static, so I can't use any static images instead of text. So I need real text object being drawn. But I also need the font size of this text to change if, for example, length of text is larger then some given value. UILabel has option of auto shrinking text but I don't know how to make it draw border around each symbol. 
So is there any way to autoshrink text manually drawn by CGContextShowTextAtPoint() or at least to measure the length in points of text, drawn with particular font settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw with core graphics and set a minimum font size to resize the text to fit:

```
[YOURSTRING drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(1, 1) forWidth:250 withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] minFontSize:10 actualFontSize:nil lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentNone];
```

You can also get the size of a text string using this:

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [YOURSTRING sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT)];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's great solution. Drawing this way even uses UIKit coordinate system instead of Quartz one, so there is no need to do coordinate system transformation.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` in terms of Context

Comment: I suggested a UIKit function to draw the text, which automatically shrinks the text. If you need to draw in multithreading, then you'll need to calculate your self the font size that will fit in the rect you have and then draw it